# Unexpected displaymath in math environment with \underbrace

Tags: math-mode

I would like to stay in math mode by using $ delimiters. But when I use this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

$\big(\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{j,k}x_k\big)_{1\leq k\leq n}
=\big(\underbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n\delta_{j,k}}_{1_A}x_k\big)_{1\leq k\leq n}$

\end{document}
```

I get this:

[image]

On the right, it looks as if I was in displaymath. Why? Should I use `\textstyle` whenever I use `\underbrace`?

Comment: why do you want this expression to be inline math rather than display?

Comment: When you add an underbrace, it increases the depth of the expression so much that there is almost a guarantee of uneven linespacing below it. Because of this, it is a "(not unreasonable) assum[p]tion" (to quote D.Carlisle) for `\underbrace` to expect it has been used in a display, where that extra vertical space is not a problem.

Comment: @Dan feel free to edit my typos (I fixed that one thanks:-)

Answer (score 7):

underbrace is defined in the latex format as

```
\def\underbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\displaystyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
          %%%%%%%%%%%%
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
```

There is a (not unreasonable:-) assumption that no one would want textstyle here. So if you really do want that you would have to re-assert it in the argument as you suggest in your question.

Answer (score 3):

So given that David has told you why it is that way, there are several things you can do with that information.  You can create your own macro `\tunderbrace` that is just like `\underbrace` but in text style, by altering the existing definition.

Or you, just for fun, create your own version, `\Tunderbrace`, using stacks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine, scalerel, graphicx}
\makeatletter
\def\tunderbrace#1{\mathop{\vtop{\m@th\ialign{##\crcr
   $\hfil\textstyle{#1}\hfil$\crcr
          %%%%%%%%%%%%
   \noalign{\kern3\p@\nointerlineskip}%
   \upbracefill\crcr\noalign{\kern3\p@}}}}\limits}
\makeatother
\newcommand\Tunderbrace[2]{\mathop{\ensurestackMath{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\tmp$}%
  \stackunder[1pt]{%
    \stackunder[0pt]{\tmp}{\rotatebox{90}{\scaleto[2ex]{\{}{\wd0}}}%
  }{%
    \scriptstyle #2%
  }%
}}}
\parskip 1em
\begin{document}
$\tunderbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{j,k}}_{1_A}x_k$\par
$\Tunderbrace{\sum_{j=1}^n \delta_{j,k}}{1_A}x_k$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Or you could set the entire expression in display math:-)

Comment: Oh you deleted it just as I was agreeing:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are not being "not unreasonable", are you?  Or maybe you are, when I work my way through the triple-negation.  Oh, my head hurts.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes You don't really need something as powerful as `stackengine` to define a macro like `\newcommand\tunderbrace[1]{\underbrace{\textstyle{#1}}}`

Comment: @Dan Indeed.  As I said, it was merely "for fun"...just honing my stacking skills.  But readers should take note of your comment.